# Maven Build Jar with Resource in Package

Tags: java, eclipse, jar, maven-3

I'm trying to build a Jar with Maven, and I would like to put one of my resources directly in the Java packages, but I cannot figure out how to do so.  For example, if my maven project looks like this

```
src/main/java
--com
---company
----application
-----database


src/main/resources
--config.xml
```

I want a jar where config.xml ends up in com/company/application/database.  Any idea how to do so? I'm using eclipse 4.5.1 with maven 3.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to put config.xml in com/company/application/database you can create that directory under resources and put config.xml in there.

```
cd src/main/resources
mkdir -p com/company/application/database
mv config.xml /com/company/application/database/
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured this out. Here is what when in my pom.xml:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.7</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>copy-resources</id>
                    <phase>validate</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>copy-resources</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <outputDirectory>${project.build.outputDirectory}/com/company/app/common/tablebeans/shared</outputDirectory>
                        <resources>
                            <resource>
                                <directory>${basedir}/src/main/resources</directory>
                                <includes>
                                    <include>**/*hibernate*xml</include>
                                </includes>
                            </resource>
                        </resources>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
```

Comment: This works, but @ozborn's solution is, of course, much simpler.

Comment: Thanks, if it works well for you feel free to accept my answer below. :)